# How to detect if session is about to expire?

Tags: session, go, gorilla

I am using Gorilla Sessions for my Go website to manage user logins.
Sometimes when a user leaves their computer for an hour or so the session expires but they have no idea about it. So the user goes on with their work but as soon as they try to save their progress, they get logged out. Is there any way I could detect if a user's session is about to expire, so I can automatically save their work or display a warning message?

Comment: If you have the pending work to save, then why not just save it? If the work is on a remote client (e.g. web browser), then the client needs to do that.

Comment: If the cookie contains its expiration data, the client could check via JavaScript. If it does not, the client would need to make a call to the server via JavaScript to find out if it's expired or how soon it's expiring in order to notify the user. How you notify them without losing their work in progress is an exercise in UX design.

Comment: @Adrian, session cookies are typically (hopefully!) flagged as HttpOnly and thus inaccessible from JS.

Comment: Yep. So, pretty much as I wrote, if you can check it directly from JS, check it directly from JS, and if you can't, check it by making a call to the server from JS.

Comment: Or add the expiration time to the markup, in a meta tag, for instance. If you do that also put the server's current time in as a reference. The client's clock is obviously unreliable by itself.

Comment: Adding expiration information in the response to the requests and having the frontend deal with asking the server to save and notifying the user is how I'd do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

As soon as the client logs in they receive the session expiration date from the server. Then I set up a timer on client side, which after being idle for X (10 in my case) minutes, calls the API in every minute and checks if the session is still alive and if there is more time left than two minutes. If only two minutes left, I raise a warning message on the client side to inform the user that their session is about to expire (I also used this event to fire the auto save functions).